# Azure: Http request fail past x time

Tags: azure, request

I have a ajax that calls a function.
This function spend 5 minutes to complete.
When I run in my machine, it's everything ok.
But when I run in my deployed web site in azure, the request return with error 500 when past 3.5 minutes. But it's continue running and complete the work, I see in the database.
The response is blank.
Any help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can change approach and use web sockets.
5 minutes is a long time to hold a connection, a lot can happen in 5 minutes, 
Different approach would be to return a guid before you start the process and make a lull request from the client every 10 sec or so until the process state is changed to finished and you can return the result.
Good luck.